# Weird Safari rendering

Tags: safari

I'm testing the new template for a website that I'm working for, and on Safari I have a really weird behaviour where a piece of page (a table) goes far on the right, about 631 pixels, and I don't have any idea on why this is happening and how to fix it.

Someone can help me? Here the page:

http://www.ilsegnale.it/?tpl=502

Comment: You shouldn't use tables for layout.

Comment: That's not really an answer, is it.

Comment: i've made a try to use tableless layout, but the issues of all the browers were really too much for a (imho) complicated layout like this (you don't want to see this layout talbeless in IE6 without going nuts). I know that tableless would be better, but i don'thave time to fix all the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The height of the `<a>` tags inside your menu is set to 43px. This is too tall, and the box extends below the menu bar. Because your `<li>`s are `float:left`, the table "catches" on the last one.

One way to solve this is to add `style='clear:both'` to the table in question. You could also reduce the height of the `<a>`s to about 35px.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to get at, but his explanation was much better. Nice work J.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your last button 'Redazione' is pushing against the Table content of your main featurelet. Try taking the height sizing off that button. Or you can try displaying your table as a block, which should also work. Odds are, if that button *is* the issue, your best solution is going to be to make sure that UL becomes the basis for the margin between your navbar and middle content. You should always use a container element to set outward margins, and make sure your elements' dimensions don't extend past their container.

Comment: adding surrounding divs both to the nav or the content didn't solve the problem, but adding a <br> after the UL closing that allowed the right alignment of the table, but adding a lot of space between the nav and the content